# Is there a way to allow users to input something in JS

Tags: javascript

How do I allow users to input something in the terminal when JS is running?
This is what I'm trying to do to be more specific.

```js
Hello, What is your Name?
> Theodore
Oh, Hello Theodore!
```

I couldn't find anything that includes anything about this. Is that even possible in JS? If you have any solutions that could answer this question. please help, possibly with information or documentation about it.

Comment: google readLine()

Comment: Alright. @danh... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are still looking for an answer, please have a look at the snippet below.

For more details, refer to https://www.codecademy.com/articles/getting-user-input-in-node-js. The example below is almost a copy/paste approach from the aforementioned page.

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
   
  readline.question('What is your name? ', name => {
    console.log(`Oh, Hello ${name}!`);
    readline.close();
  });
```